# Controller not found with personalized route file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I've created my own Route file using AppServiceProvider,

```
public function boot(){
    $this->loadRoutesFrom('routes/test/routes.php');
}
```

The routes are working but they doesn't found the Controllers

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
```

ReflectionException (-1)
Class TestController does not exist

Maybe I missed something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map routes in your RouteServiceProvider.php, Check the example of web routes.

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
        {
            Route::group([
                'middleware' => 'web',
                'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            ], function ($router) {
                require base_path('routes/web.php');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Thanks to vikalp.

It was so easy, I didn´t have to touch AppServiceProvider, the answer was in obviously in RouteServiceProvider.php, I just add my customized route file to mapWebRoutes();

```
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    /* My route-file */
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/test/test_routes.php'));
}
```